# Unable to load Fixtures couse of foreign key constraint fails EComDev PHPUnit

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, ecomdev-phpunit

i want to add a complete order in my Test by a fixture.

The file looks like that:

```
  eav:
    #==================================================
    # Customers
    #==================================================

    customer:
      -
        entity_id: 1238299
        entity_type_id: 1
        attribute_set_id: 0
        website_id: 1
        default_billing: 2606480
        default_shipping: 2606480
        otherData
        otherData


  tables:
    #==================================================
    # Orders
    #==================================================

    sales/order:
        entity_id: 2842007
        store_id: 1
        customer_id: 1238299
        billing_address_id: 6269997
        quote_address_id: ~
        quote_id: 21682178
        shipping_address_id: 6269998
        increment_id: 102468857
        otherData
        otherData



    #==================================================
    # Adresses
    #==================================================

    sales/order_address:
      - entity_id: 6269998
        parent_id: 2842007
        customer_address_id:
        quote_address_id:
        otherData
        otherData

      - entity_id: 6269997
        parent_id: 2842007
        customer_address_id: 2606480
        quote_address_id:
        otherData
        otherData


    #=====================================
    # Order items
    #=====================================

    sales/order_item:
      -
        item_id: 5033860
        order_id: 2842007
        otherData
        otherData
      -
        item_id: 5033861
        order_id: 2842007
        parent_item_id: ~
        otherData
        otherData


    #===================================
    # Payments
    #===================================
    sales/order_payment:
      -
        entity_id: 3701517
        parent_id: 2842007


    #===================================
    # Quots
    #===================================
    sales/quote:
```

When i know start the test and load this fixture i become this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`unit_test`.`sales_flat_order_address`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ADDRESS_PARENT_ID_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_order` (`entity_id`) ON D)' in /Users/xxx/workspace/magento_shop/vendor/xxx/ext.magento.ecomdev.phpunit/app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/Model/Mysql4/Fixture.php on line 78
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`unit_test`.`sales_flat_order_address`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ADDRESS_PARENT_ID_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_order` (`entity_id`) ON D) in /Users/xxx/workspace/magento_shop/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228

Did i have to load them in another order, or is something missing?
Maybe is there a way to deactivate foreign key constraint?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, wow...
After some hours of debugging the wrong thing i found out that the sales/order has to be an array like this:

> ```
> sales/order:
>   -
>     entity_id: 2842007
>     store_id: 1
>     customer_id: 1238299
>     billing_address_id: 6269997
>     quote_address_id: ~
>     quote_id: 21682178
>     shipping_address_id: 6269998
>     increment_id: 102468857
>     otherData
>     otherData
> ```

after that it inserts the order the right way and not only with null values and then i can perfectly add the addresses in fact that the entity_id of order is valid.